# Moving overlay content in time with HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, json, html, video, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video which I has elements laid on top.

I want the content to follow some objects in the video.
What is the best way for me to do this, so i can control the CSS top and left attributes ( this is how i see the content moving on top of the video).

I want to make sure that the content positions is always kept in sync with the time of the video. If a user restarts the video or skips to a certain point it would be good if the content knew where they were meant to be.

I have seen some examples of this where they use JSON to control the content position and at what time is should show, hide and move.
I am not sure how this was hooked up with the video player and time of the video.

I have not been able to find anything to help explain the JSON method or other ways of doing it.
Is there a demo of something similar or an example someone could create.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend [Popcorn.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/) combined with [Popcorn Base Plugin](https://github.com/brianchirls/popcorn-base/), which together should do all of that. In particular, take a look at these [examples](https://github.com/brianchirls/popcorn-base/#examples).

Popcorn Base Plugin is a wrapper for creating your own Popcorn plugins, but it comes with a few plugins built already, and all of them have full keyframe animation. I suggest that you start with the "style" plugin, which will take any existing DOM element and animate its CSS properties in time with the video, including "top", "left", etc.

Popcorn doesn't directly take a JSON blob for all the animations, but it should be simple enough to traverse such an object and make the appropriate calls to Popcorn's methods. Both projects are well documented and have good, simple examples.

*Full disclosure: I built Popcorn Base Plugin, so I may be a bit biased.*

Comment: Awesome Great work! Thanks @brianchirls. Is there an example of how to manage multiple elements with the style plugin over different time periods?

Comment: Just saw your example files. So no worries about the question above. Thanks again @brianchirls

Comment: Great. The style plugin has a "target" option that will select any element to adjust. If you leave it out, by default it selects your video.